# Python 2: Next input line not showing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have tried to run one simple code for enter the user input and print that value like below :

```
num1 = input('Enter first number: ')
num2 = input('Enter second number: ')
sum = float(num1) + float(num2)
print('The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}'.format(num1, num2, sum))
```

Now when i run this code then its only provide the option to enter the first input like below:

```
Enter first number:
```

once i input the number in this line then nothing to happened and also not showing the next one line for the input.

Can you please let me know if i missed anything here? or any idea please share.

Comment: It is working fine for me with both python2 and python3

Comment: it's working fine for me. please double check from your end.

Comment: Did you press [ENTER] after inputting the first number?

Comment: Yes i press the enter but cursor is going into next empty line.

Comment: I have used the Sublime editor.

Comment: How are you running it? I recommend running the script from a shell/terminal.

Comment: I have use the Ctl +b shortcut key for run that code. Its showing the first line properly and i also able to input the first line

Comment: Its working fine in Shell script ( Command: python demo.py ). what is the issue to run in editor?

Comment: Is any one suggest me to best way to run the python code? i am new in python so not sure what is the best way to work on this?